# Upload Zip to S3 with Heroku, upzip and allow others access extracted files with unique link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I have an interesting situation where the user would upload a zip file, that file needs to be moved to S3, unzipped and made public to other users through a unique link.

For example:

I upload awesome.zip (lets say it contains its own mini webpage), it gets moved to S3 and unzipped and placed into 123456/. Then if I want to share my mini webpage with someone, they could go to www.mysite.com/{username}/item/123456.

Is this possible? Can anyone give me any guidance on how to go about it? Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Joe Chin

Answer (score 3):

Files can not be unzipped on S3.  It is a limitation of the platform last I checked.  How I handled zipped files was to extract them on my local server and the upload the extracted files to s3. You can use the aws-sdk gem (official amazon gem) to upload the extracted files to s3.